# FuelSDK-Node Properties to send

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, node.js

I'm trying to access Data Extensions' Data (Rows, columns, etc...) through [Node API](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node).

```
const ET_Client = require('../node_modules/sfmc-fuelsdk-node');

const clientId = 'clientId'
const clientSecret = 'clientSecret'
const stack = 'S10'
const obj = {
  origin: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/',
  authOrigin: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
  soapOrigin: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/',
  authOptions: { 
    authVersion: 2,
    accountId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  }
}
const client = new ET_Client(clientId, clientSecret, stack, obj);
const props = [
  'Name',
  'FieldType',
  'MaxLength', 
  'DataExtension.CustomerKey',
  'IsPrimaryKey'
  ];

const filter = {
    leftOperand: 'DataExtension.CustomerKey',
    operator: 'equals',
    rightOperand: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}

client.dataExtensionColumn({props, filter}).get((err, resp) => {
  if(err){
    console.log("\n\nerror \n\n")
    console.log(err)
  }else{
    console.log(resp)
  }
});
```

but I don't know for sure what props I can Send in `client.dataExtensionColumn({props })`. When I remove this props from the "request" (`client.dataExtensionColumn({props, filter}`) I get the following error:

> { error: 'A property list is required for DE column retrieval.',  
>   documentation:  
>    'https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extension-columns/data-extension-column-retrieve.html'
>   }

And then, when I try to access the link received, I get Internal Server Error

[image]

The docs are a little confusing, Where can I find the properties I can send in this (and to others Objects: DataExtension, DataExtensionRow, etc...) request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, those requests use SFMC SOAP API. You can find the corresponding properties in these docs:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionfield.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm

The properties for DataExtensionRow would just be the fields in your Data Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Tyler answer... I also had opened a case and the support answered the same thing Tyler did, but with and Addition:

> [...] However this is not documented because FuelSDK-Node is not the
>   functionality from Marketing cloud, It is developed by third party
>   which makes an API call towards Marketing cloud. So all the properties
>   of DataExtensionField and other objects may or may not be supported by
>   FuelSDK-Node.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a while testing right now. I want to read a few data extensions with their columns and the package sfmc-fuelsdk-node is bad documentated.

It took a while until the filter for the data extension name worked. It wasn't possible for me to use the operator "equals". It worked only with "like". Maybe that's a help for someone else.

```
const ET_Client = require('sfmc-fuelsdk-node');
const client = new ET_Client('client_id', 'client_secret', 'S10', {
    origin: 'https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    authOrigin: 'https://xxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    soapOrigin: 'https://xxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    authOptions: {
        authVersion: 2,
        accountId: 1337 // mid
    }
});
function getColumns(dataExtension) {
    const de = client.dataExtensionColumn({
        props: [
            'Name'
        ],
        filter: {
            leftOperand: 'CustomerKey',
            operator: 'like',
            rightOperand: dataExtension.CustomerKey // customer key of the data extension
        }
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        de.get((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            if (result.body.Results.length === 0) {
                return resolve([]);
            }
            const columns = [];
            result.body.Results.forEach(row => {
                columns.push(row.Name);
            });
            resolve(columns);
        });
    });
}

getColumns({
    CustomerKey: 'xxx' // customer key of data extension
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You can use the `equals` operator with `leftOperand: 'DataExtension.CustomerKey'`